# How to enable the sound while screen recording a Zoom meeting on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, display, recording, zoom.app

I'm trying to record the screen while attending a Zoom meeting on iPhone, but the video after the recording seems to have no sound!
Before I started recording, I have turned the microphone on! But It also did not work!

How can I solve such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Zoom](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/203066759-Recording-on-iOS-and-Android), local recording on iOS isn't supported.

Recording is only available to paid users of Zoom and only for [cloud recording](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/203741855-Cloud-Recording) by the meeting organizer.